# Multiple joins in linq using repository pattern generics

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have implemented a repository pattern that contains a list of generic methods to perform CRUD operations to the database. This is illustrated below.

```
public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        _entities = context;
        _dbset = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnmerable<T> GetAll()
    {

        return _dbset.AsEnumerable<T>();
    }
```

Next, I have a **service** layer that is implements the above repository class.

**TruckService**

In this class, to make use of the repository generic methods, I have the below code:

```
private IRepository<Workers> _repositoryWorkers;
private IRepository<Jobs> _repositoryJobs;
private IRepository<Depts> _repositoryDepts;


public WorkerService(IRepository<Workers> repositoryWorkers, IRepository<Jobs> repositoryJobs, IRepository<Depts> repositoryDepts) 
{
  _repositoryWorkers = repositoryWorkers;
  _repositoryJobs = repositoryJobs;
  _repositoryDepts = repositoryDepts
}

// a query that makes multiple joins to retrieve data.
from h in _repositoryWorkers.GetAll()
join p in _repositoryJobs.GetAll() on h.Id equals p.Id
join q in _repositoryDepts.GetAll() on h.Id equals q.Id
```

So, in the above **TruckService** class, I have implemented the `IRepository` interface to inherits the generic methods. In this class, I am making a query that performs multiple joins to obtain data from the database. I am getting all the data correctly but I have read somewhere that this approach is :

> mixing and matching repository-based queries and LINQ queries. Rather
>   than doing a true join, you're fetching all the rows for each table
>   and then joining them in-memory

So, in this case could someone please advise me a better / efficient approach of doing this multiple joins ?

*Note that I am new with EF, and this is my first project using repository pattern.

Comment: Specialised methods on your repositories. E.g  `GetJobsByWorkerId`

Comment: `_repositoryJobs.GetAll() on h.Id equals p.Id` you are effectively downloading the entire table just for in-memory querying. Pro tip: do NOT follow the repository pattern when you are just learning Entity Framework. The Repository pattern may be good for some use cases, it is not for EF. As an extra comment: whenever you see `IEnumerable<T>` when working with Entity Framework, you are doing something wrong

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto : Also, regarding the constructor `WorkerService`, I notice that if I need to joins other tables, I would need to specify the `IRepository` of that table as a parameter in the constructor. Hence, the constructor would be overloaded with lots of constructors which I think is a bad approach. 

Please could you advise me an alternative ?

Comment: My suggestion: remove anything related to repositories and use EF directly, plain and simple

Comment: So you mean that if I have to make joins with table, I should not use repositories at all ?

Comment: EF and repositories is noooo good. Either one or the other. There is a place for repositories, but only for _simple_ CRUD.

Comment: So, ideally I should make an instance of my DbContext and use the object to query my tables with joins ? Please someone confirm.

Comment: Yes, remove those classes/interfaces and new up `DbContext` instances and use that.

Comment: Imagine an employee table of 20 columns and 100,000 rows. a query ending up only needing a single employee. So rather than downloading 20 fields of used data, the service now downloads 2,000,000 fields, and still only using 20 of them. And this is only between your database and the service. That is a lot of unnecessary bytes floating around.

Comment: Shortly - don't use repository anti-pattern. Use full capabilities of `DbContext` and EF model, especially navigation properties, eager loading, projection queries etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev : What do you mean by repository anti-pattern ?

Comment: @Rob : Yes you're right. I was unsure about this.

Comment: *make an instance of my DbContext and use the object to query my tables with joins* Almost. But now not using joins but navigation properties. Repository is an anti pattern because 1) usually it's nothing but a thin (= useless) wrapper around a `DbSet`, 2) it hampers LINQ query composition, and 3) it introduces ambiguous responsibilities ("which repository is responsible for my nested entities?").

Answer (score 2):

Returning IEnumerable set of all entities in your database is a perfect way to shoot yourself in the foot. Avoid doing this, because it loads all data in-memory.

You can use IQueryable, unlike IEnumerable, it executes query in the database, you can add filtering to it, and it won't actually perform the query and load results until you materialize (like calling ToList(), FirstOrDefault() and several others).

Foreign keys, navigation properties are all tools you can use to navigate between entities easily, and save yourself a lot of explicit joins. You can use things like eager loading for navigation properties you expect to use often. One of the main goals of EF is to help you write less code. It saves you lot of time and also makes the places where you can mistake less (less code, less mistakes, but still be careful when using it).

Whether you want to use repository pattern or not, it's your choice. Some people see it is an unnecessary abstraction over the abstraction already provided by EF context and sets. Some people see it as a necessity that separates business logic from database access. However, it is important to read a lot about it, before using it, especially if you are new to EF. Here is what [Microsoft give as an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) in their documentation.

Comment: It is funny how they never show how to write `joins` with repository pattern, oh wait... you can't without exposing `IQueryable`. MSDN examples should be buried in the ground with people who wrote them, they almost always use bad pratices.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to return `IQueryable<T>` from generic repository, so you can modify later the query in specific inheriting repositories.

However in order to have `Include` in generic repostiory, you can pass to GetAll method `params Func<T, object>[]` with properties to include and then aggregate this into query.
See example here on [this gist.](https://gist.github.com/oneillci/3205384)

However, you won't be able to use `ThenInclude`. Consider going for returning `IQueryable` so you can later modify query.

Comment: Returning `IQueryable` completely defeates the purpose of having repositories. The point of having repositories is to abstract database layer. If `IQueryable` starts leaking to other layers, then you cannot swap database implementations, because `IQueryable` is specific to Entity Framework.